# how to find a number inside an id and check the checkbox with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, find, checkbox

this might be a bit confusing but here it goes. I have a first set of checkboxes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="quick" value="6" />
<input type="checkbox" id="quick" value="3" />
```

And a second set of checkboxes like this:

```
<div class="check1"><input type="checkbox" id="1,3,4" value="6" /></div>
<div class="check1"><input type="checkbox" id="1" value="6" /></div>
<div class="check1"><input type="checkbox" id="6,4" value="6" /></div>
```

I need to get the value of the first checkbox and check in if that value exists in the id array of the second set of checkboxes and check them if it returns true. This is what I have so far but it is not working:

```
$('#quick').click(function(){
        var perId = $(this).val();
        $('#check1 input[type="checkbox"]').attr('id').find(perId).attr('checked', true);
        });
```

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No two elements on the same page should share the same ID. And "1,3,4" (though legal under HTML5) is not an appropriate ID value either.

Comment: I agree it is not a valid id, maybe I can place it in a class element. I get this array from mysql.

Comment: Have you considered using `data-` attributes instead?

Comment: sure I will use whatever it takes, but will you please help me achieve what I am trying to do? Thanks

Comment: @liveandream: use `data-id="1,2,3"` and access it using `.data('id')`. PS: is it stored as `1,2,3` - comma separated string in database? If not and you have php array - then better would be to serialize it to json using `json_encode` and jquery will decode it for you

Comment: I will definitely use the data-id idea, but no it is not a php array. Just a comma seperated string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed a few things around to make the code more sensible (please let me know if I broke anything).

1. The "quick" checkboxes had their id removed, and replaced with a common name.
2. The various checkboxes within .check1 had their id values converted to `data-set` attributes.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="quick" value="6" />
<input type="checkbox" name="quick" value="3" />

<div class="check1">
    <input type="checkbox" data-set="1,3,4" value="6" />
    <input type="checkbox" data-set="1,3"   value="6" />
    <input type="checkbox" data-set="6,4"   value="6" />
</div>​
```

```js
$(function () {

    "use strict";

    var $quick = $("[name=quick]"),
        $dSets = $(".check1 :checkbox");

    // We've changed a checkbox
    $quick.on("change", function () {
        // Uncheck all data-set elements
        $dSets.prop("checked", false);
        // Run through all checked quick elements
        $quick.filter(":checked").each(function (index, quick) {
            // Determine whether each data set element should be checked
            $dSets.prop("checked", function () {
                // Get array of values
                var set = $(this).data("set").toString().split(",");
                // Should this box be checked
                return this.checked || $.inArray(quick.value, set) > -1;
            });
        });
    });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u2q8P/4/